# The exact way to execute javascript console.log useing selenium in python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, webdriver

What I've tried:

```
driver.execute_script("console.log('help me to see console print')")
```

But No any result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After execution javascript, need sometime to load it into browser dom.
So I added some time sleep under that code line.

```
driver.execute_script("console.log('help me to see console print')")
time.sleep(10)
```

Now it was printed:

> help me to see console print

Answer (score 3):

You have got it!

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
driver.execute_script(f"console.log('{driver.current_url}');")
```

[image]

Comment: @toptalent I just added the `get` for the example. if you need to access the log from the browser to your code that's a different question...

Comment: @MosheSlavin semi colon is not mandatory in javascript

Comment: @PDHide correct! it's just a convention thanks for pointing that out.